# Telling if the user or the OS initiated Android C2DM registration

Tags: android, android-c2dm

In my Activity when the user says they want to enable notifications I call the following method:

```
private Intent buildRegistrationIntent(boolean register) {
    String intentName = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent." + (register ? "REGISTER" : "UNREGISTER");
    Intent intent = new Intent(intentName);
    intent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0)); // boilerplate
    intent.putExtra("sender", "xxxxx@gmail.com");
    intent.putExtra("TEST", "test extras");

    return intent;
}
```

In my C2DM BroadcastReceiver I have this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    log.fine(Boolean.toString(intent.getExtras().containsKey("TEST")));
    log.fine(Boolean.toString(intent.getExtras().containsKey("registration_id")));

    if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
        handleRegistration(context, intent);
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
        handleMessage(context, intent);
    }
}
```

The problem is, the "TEST" extra never gets sent to the C2DM BroadcastReceiver. The output from the below lines is "False" then "True" i.e. it has the registration_id, but not TEST.

Is there any way to pass some user defined data to the BroadcastReceiver or does the C2DM infrastructure eat the original intent and create a new one with just the registration_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is impossible. Whatever receives the REGISTER intent doesn't pass it on to onReceive.

Answer (score 0):

Why you send TEST via Intent?
You need send push notification messages not via intents.

Comment: I want the C2DM BroadcastReceiver to tell whether the registration intent was from the user or from the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at onHandleIntent(Intent intent) method in [C2DMBaseReceiver.java](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/trunk/android/c2dm/com/google/android/c2dm/C2DMBaseReceiver.java) class. You can override method onMessage() in your C2DMReceiver.java class extended [C2DMBaseReceiver.java](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/trunk/android/c2dm/com/google/android/c2dm/C2DMBaseReceiver.java)